# Using Enum in if-else in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following for loops with if-else condition. However, it is not quite intituitve for others to read the code at a first glance. therefore I am thinking to use `Enum` here.

```
 for row in 0..<result.count {
   for column in 0..<result[row].count {
       if column == 0 {
         // add hotels here      
       } else if column == 1 {
         // add motels here
       }
   }
}
```

I am trying to use the following enum, but I am confused how to put into if-else condition.

```
enum ResortColumn {
  case hotel
  case motel
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and post your result declaration. Looks like it is `[[Int]]`. You should declare it as `[[ResortColumn]]`. Btw I would rename it ro `Resort`

Comment: Where does the value of `result: [[Int]]` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare your enum type to an integer, you need to declare it an Int and compare its rawValue.

```
enum ResortColumn: Int {
  case hotel
  case motel
}

if column == ResultColumn.hotel.rawValue { // etc.
```

See the second "enum Planet" example on this page, and read the rest for a full understanding of Swift enums:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html

Answer (score 1):

```
enum ResortColumn: Int {
  case hotel
  case motel
}

for row in 0 ..< result.count {
   for column in 0 ..< result[row].count {
    let resortColumn = ResortColumn(rawValue: column)
    switch resortColumn {
    case .hotel:
        // add hotels here
    case .motel:
        // add motels here
    }
   }
}
```

This is the best what I can come up with the context you gave. In this case, it does really matter what is behind the `result` variable